# Redis send a object with the message to use on method calling

Tags: object, redis, stackexchange.redis

Hello i got redis as a backplane to my SignalR application and i want the redis to send a message to specific groups no matter what SignalR instance they are sitting on. I got the SignalR and redis setup the problem i am now getting is that i want to send down data that is of an object type to be used by the SignalR method that sends it down to the client. so first here is the method that publishes

```
public async Task RedisBroadcast(string group, string message, object data)
    {
        var pub = Connection.GetSubscriber();
        Program.WriteConsole($"> Broadcasting to Group: {group} Message: {message}");
        await pub.PublishAsync(group, message);
    }
```

i would need the parameter data to be sent down with the Publish message because later on were in the method that the sub recieves the message i want to do something similar to this

```
await sub.SubscribeAsync(group, (channel, message) =>
        {
            Program.WriteConsole("Got notification: " + (string)message);

            switch (message)
            {
                case "TopPlayers":
                    TopPlayersbroadcast(group, message, data);
                    break;
            }
        });
```

so depending on the message i call different methods that then broadcasts the message with data to all subbed clients. Is this someway possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *possible*, but you'll need to encode that data *inside your payload*, i.e. inside `message`, the `RedisValue` that you get in the `(channel, message)` pair. The SE.Redis library very deliberately doesn't get opinionated on what payloads should look like, so it doesn't assume you want to encode something like that. Note that because it is a `RedisValue`, not a `string`, you can do some more nuanced things than just passing your original `string message`.

If this was me, I would probably look at something like protobuf-net and object inheritance in this scenario - since a: it works nicely with SE.Redis since SE.Redis supports binary payloads, and b: the inheritance allows you to represent the data fairly easily - presumably embedding `message` and `data` into the same fundamental message as a base-type, but *lots* of different layouts exist for similar schemes.